# Function over multiple Spark DataFrame columns at once

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, md5, user-defined-functions

I need to calculate a md5 hash over multiple dataframe columns at once.

**Function**

```
def md5 = udf((s: String) => toHex(MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(s.getBytes("UTF-8"))))
def toHex(bytes: Array[Byte]): String = bytes.map("%02x".format(_)).mkString("")
```

**Example with one column**

```
var test_df = load_df.as('a).select($"a.attr1", md5($"a.attr2").as("hash_key"))

+-------------+--------------------+
|     attr1   |            hash_key|
+-------------+--------------------+
|9/1/2015 0:23|7a2f516dad8f13ae1...|
|9/1/2015 0:31|339c72b1870c3a6be...|
|9/1/2015 0:19|7065847af7abc6bce...|
|9/1/2015 1:32|38c7276958809893b...|
```

The generation with one column (a.attr2) works pretty good but i can't find any good way to insert/concatenate multiple columns into the md5() function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `concat_ws` as followed:

```
md5(concat_ws(",",$"a.attr2",$"a.attr3",$"a.attr4"))
```

Here is an example :

```
Seq(("a","b","c")).toDF("x","y","z").withColumn("foo", md5(concat_ws(",",$"x",$"y",$"z"))).show(false)
// +---+---+---+--------------------------------+
// |x  |y  |z  |foo                             |
// +---+---+---+--------------------------------+
// |a  |b  |c  |a44c56c8177e32d3613988f4dba7962e|
// +---+---+---+--------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would do the concatenation inside the UDF, this gives you more flexibility:

e.g. passing array of Strings:

```
val md5 = udf((arrs:Seq[String]) => {
  val s = arrs.mkString(",")
  // do something with s
  s
 })    

df.withColumn("md5",md5(array($"x",$"y",$"z")))
```

Or even passing the entire row, which would also work if you have columns of mixed type:

```
val md5 = udf((r:Row) => {
  val s = r.mkString(",")
  // do something with s
  s
 })

df.withColumn("md5",md5(struct($"x",$"y",$"z")))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to concate all columns using a custom delimiter, use this:

```
df.withColumn('row_hash', md5(concat_ws('||', *df.columns)))
```

Useful for calculating row hash.